# Disable specific "selectize" dropdown option

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, selectize.js

I am trying to disable shipping location in selectize drop down for already selected for same code. for example in the screenshot you can see code  "Apple" first time shippping locatin i have already selected "Mumbai" now i try to add code "Apple" second time now in the shipping location "Mumbai" should be disabled but "Surat" only enable to select.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please refer below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fruit').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "1") {
                $('#Location').find('option[value=1]').attr("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

//html

```
<select id="fruit">
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Cherry</option>
</select>

<select id="Location">
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="1">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="2">Delhi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: there is selectize js  used for drop down. it should disable using selectize js.

Comment: i have use selectize js.

your stuff not working selectize js.

Comment: sohil, i'll test code with the selectize.js and share the solution with you.

Comment: checkout this link if you still in need [to disable option](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/1248)